# Prove $\lim_n z^n/n$ is infinity

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

Okay. So z is a complex number which $|z|>1$.
Now we have to prove $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{n}{z^n}= 0$ which is of course equivalent to $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{z^n}{n} =\pm\infty$.
So how can we do that?
The most i have reached is proving there exists an m which for every $n$ that is bigger than or equal to $m$, $\dfrac{|z^n|}{n}\geq 1$!!!

Comment: Take $z=-2$ and see  what happens

Comment: Your last statement is false. Take z = 2 e^i. It won't have any real power.

Comment: Oops... Yep your right. edited and fixed. thanks for the heads up but you get the point...

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Use the polar form $z=\rho e^{i\theta}$ where $\rho=|z|$.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$|z|
=1+y
$
where
$y > 0$.

Then,
from the first 3 terms
of the binomial theorem,
for $n \ge 2$,
$|z|^n
=(1+y)^n
\ge 1+ny+n(n-1)y^2/2
> n(n-1)y^2/2
$,
so
$\frac{n}{|z|^n}
<\frac{n}{n(n-1)y^2/2}
=\frac{2}{(n-1)y^2}
\to 0
$
as
$n \to \infty$.

Note that,
by taking the first
$m+1$ terms of
the binomial theorem,
we get,
for $n > m$,

$\begin{align*}
|z|^n
&=(1+y)^n\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} y^k\\
&\ge \binom{n}{m+1} y^{m+1}\\
&= \frac{n!}{(m+1)!(n-m-1)!}y^{m+1}\\
&= \frac{\prod_{k=0}^{m}(n-k)}{(m+1)!}y^{m+1}\\
&\ge \frac{n^{m+1}\prod_{k=0}^{m}(1-k/n)}{(m+1)!}y^{m+1}\\
\text{so}\\
\frac{|z|^n}{n^m}
&\ge \frac{n\prod_{k=0}^{m}(1-k/n)}{(m+1)!}y^{m+1}\\
&\to \infty\\
\end{align*}
$

since,
for
$n > m^2$,
$\prod_{k=0}^{m}(1-k/n)
>1-\sum_{k=0}^{m}(k/n)
= 1-\frac{m(m+1)}{2n}
> \frac12
$.